# onReceive not calling in PendingIntent.getBroadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

Again i have a problem with Broadcasts..

Fragment:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,AlarmReceiver.class);
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);
int id = (int) alarms_ID;
i.putExtra("_id",id);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Calender calender=...;
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  Toast.makeText(context,"yap",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and the receiver in manifest:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

very simple code but still not working...
This code work in activity maybe the problem is the fragment?
If you need more information just say it.

Comment: I have edited my answer, replace context with getActivity()

Comment: Code looks good. Paste code after calendar maybe you have a mistake.

Comment: @krystian71115 I thought so too but i checked the year,month,day,hour and minute and they are all in time the datepicker and timepicker defined..              Edit : you are right...i replaced calender with `System.currentTimeMillis()` and this is work but the Calender is ok...

Comment: If you are calling this from other thread try runOnUiThread method in the activity and not use static fields to get context use parameter of method.

Comment: In this line: alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent); calendar - change to calender.

Comment: @krystian71115 why i need to do it? this is calendar...

Comment: Try to set as second parameter: System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 and wait 1 second and write if this works. I have writed this because in your code you have creating local variable with name "calender" not "calendar" and i thought this is a mistake.

Comment: oh ha this was mistake , in my code this is calendar. and yes , i said you System.currentTimeMillis()  work but calendar(not calender) not working.

Comment: @krystian71115 as you said the problem was the calendar. i add 1 to the month because it based on zero count and i forgot to subtract 1 from month.. thank you a lot of your time and help !!